# TSP - Branch and bound

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman, branch-and-bound

I'm trying to solve the TSP with Branch and bound algorithm.

I must build a matrix with costs but I have this problem:
I have city with coordinates x and y.

The cost of traveling is `ceil(ceil(sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2))/v)` + days spent in the city.
V is speed.

Days spent in the city depends from day when w comes to the city. 
For example if we arrived on Monday(t1) to city 1, we stay for 9 days but if we arrived on Tuesday, then we stay in the city for 4 days.

```
         x   y   t1 .        t7
city 1. 79 -36   9 4 8 5 5 7 8
city 2. 8  67    6 9 2 1 9 9 1
city 3. 29 57    7 5 10 8 10 9 4
```

How can I solve this problem using branch and bound algorithm?

Comment: Oded 
Yes but, i look for some help. I don't wont to solve this problem for me. I looke for help, to steer. 

I don't wont to write this for me.
...

Answer (score 4):

Here you go: <strike>http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node187.html</strike> - it seems to explain fairly well how this should be approached.

[Archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160520165234/http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node187.html)

Answer (score 2):

This PDF document gives a more detailed explanation of the Branch and Bound implementation for 
the Traveling Salesperson Problem:

Part 1: A solution with nodes containing partial tours with 
constraints http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_03/column7.pdf

Part 2 PDF can also be found. http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_05/column7/

Answer (score 1):

Step by step explanation of branch and bound method:

- video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR7GXoWiUw4
- book: https://archive.org/details/algorithmfortrav00litt ([link](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/46828/algorithmfortrav00litt.pdf) to download in pdf)
- implementation (C++): https://github.com/karepker/little-tsp

I hope my answer will be useful for somebody.