# Branch and bound using Perl

Tags: perl, branch-and-bound

I have a problem, I cannot find an answer to. I am using Perl. My input is a symmetric cost-matrix, kind of like the TSP.

I want to know all solutions that lie beneath my boundary, which is 10.

This is my matrix:

```
-   B   E   G   I   K   L   P   S   
B   -   10  10  2   10  10  10  10  
E   10  -   2   10  10  10  1   10  
G   10  2   -   10  2   3   3   3   
I   2   10  10  -   4   10  10  2   
K   10  10  2   4   -   10  10  3   
L   10  10  3   10  10  -   2   2   
P   10  1   3   10  10  2   -   10  
S   10  10  3   2   3   2   10  -
```

Does anybody know how to implement the branch and bound algorithm to solve this? For now, I did replace every 10 in the matrix with "-".

---

What I did so far:

```
 @verwbez = ( ["-", B, E, G, I, K, L, P, S], 
              [B,"-", 10, 10, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10], 
              [E, 10, "-", 2, 10, 10, 10, 1, 10], 
              [G, 10, 2, "-", 10, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
              [I, 2, 10, 10, "-", 4, 10, 10, 2], 
              [K, 10, 10, 2, 4, "-", 10, 10, 3], 
              [L, 10, 10, 3, 10, 10, "-", 2, 2], 
              [P, 10, 1, 3, 10, 10, 2, "-", 10], 
              [S, 10, 10, 3, 2, 3, 2, 10, "-"]);
for ($i=0;$i<=$#verwbez;$i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<=$#{$verwbez[$i]};$j++) {
        while ($verwbez[$i][$j] >=7) { 
            $verwbez[$i][$j] = "-";
        }
    }
}
```

Basically just altering the matrix, every 10 is replaced with a "-". Now I want to find all solutions that are beneath 10 and contain 4 districts where always two cities are linked together. But unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed/start...

Comment: What does a solution look like, and how is the cost matrix used to evaluate it? For the TSP, it would be an ordered sequence, as the costs refer to a path e.g. `BISLPEGK`. Is that the same for your problem, or are you constructing something other than a path?

Comment: I forgot to mention that. The letters are cities. Always two should be linked into "districts" which leads to the costs. So in the end there should always be 4 districts (containing the 8 cities) counted together with a maximum cost of 10. Every city should be mentioned just once/solution.

Comment: So it's like a segmented TSP? A solution might look like: `['BI', 'SL', "PE', 'KG']` (cost 7) . . . correct?

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Ok, I realised that my last step, altering the matrix, wasn't really necessary, so I skip that. In turn, I want it to go through the matrix stept by step and find entries <=7. But what shall I do next, when I have those entries? Should I put them into a variable? And next?
I am new in this field, so I would really appreciate it, if anybody could give me some advice/input how I may solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're unlikely to get someone to implement the [`Branch and Bound`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) algorithm for you.  However, the following stackoverflow post, [`TSP - branch and bound`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154171/tsp-branch-and-bound), has some links to some helpful resources:

1. [`Optimal Solution for TSP using Branch and Bound`](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node187.html)
2. [`B&B Implementations for the TSP`](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_03/column7.pdf) - 
   Part 1: A solution with nodes containing partial tours with 
   constraints
3. [`B&B Implementations for the TSP`](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_05/column7/) - Part 2: Single threaded solution with many inexpensive nodes

Since you appear new to perl, we can give you some quick tips

1. Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and every perl script
2. Use the [`range operator ..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) when creating an incrementing `for` loop.
3. Your `while` loop should actually be an `if` statement.
4. For increased style, consider using [`qw()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qw.html) when initializing a mixed word/number array, especially since it will allow you to easily align a multidimensional array's elements
5. Your first goal for a project like this should be to create a method to output your multidimensional array in a readable format, so you can observe and verify the changes that you're making.

All of that gives the following changes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @verwbez = (
    [qw(-  B  E  G  I  K  L  P  S )],
    [qw(B  -  10 10 2  10 10 10 10)],
    [qw(E  10 -  2  10 10 10 1  10)],
    [qw(G  10 2  -  10 2  3  3  3 )],
    [qw(I  2  10 10 -  4  10 10 2 )],
    [qw(K  10 10 2  4  -  10 10 3 )],
    [qw(L  10 10 3  10 10 -  2  2 )],
    [qw(P  10 1  3  10 10 2  -  10)],
    [qw(S  10 10 3  2  3  2  10 - )],
); 

for my $i (0 .. $#verwbez) {
    for my $j (0 .. $#{$verwbez[$i]}) {
        if ($verwbez[$i][$j] =~ /\d/ && $verwbez[$i][$j] >= 7) {
            $verwbez[$i][$j] = ".";
        }
    }
}

for (@verwbez) {
    for (@$_) {
        printf "%2s ", $_;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
 -  B  E  G  I  K  L  P  S
 B  -  .  .  2  .  .  .  .
 E  .  -  2  .  .  .  1  .
 G  .  2  -  .  2  3  3  3
 I  2  .  .  -  4  .  .  2
 K  .  .  2  4  -  .  .  3
 L  .  .  3  .  .  -  2  2
 P  .  1  3  .  .  2  -  .
 S  .  .  3  2  3  2  .  -
```

Note that B has only 1 city it's near to.  So if the goal was solving the TSP, then there isn't a trivial solution.  However, given there are only 8 cities and (n-1)! circular permutations.  That gives us just 5,040 permutations, so using brute force would totally work for finding a lowest cost solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(circular_permutations);

my @verwbez = ( ... already defined ... ); 

# Create a cost between two cities hash:
my %cost;
for my $i (1..$#verwbez) {
    for my $j (1..$#{$verwbez[$i]}) {
        $cost{ $verwbez[$i][0] }{ $verwbez[0][$j] } = $verwbez[$i][$j] if $i != $j;
    }
}

# Determine all Routes and their cost (sorted)
my @cities = keys %cost;
my @perms = circular_permutations(\@cities);
my @cost_with_perm = sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} map {
    my $perm = $_;
    my $prev = $perm->[-1];
    my $cost = 0;
    for (@$perm) {
        $cost += $cost{$_}{$prev};
        $prev = $_
    }
    [$cost, $perm]
} @perms;

# Print out lowest cost routes:
print "Lowest cost is: " . $cost_with_perm[0][0] . "\n";
for (@cost_with_perm) {
    last if $_->[0] > $cost_with_perm[0][0];
    print join(' ', @{$_->[1]}), "\n";
}
```

It ends up there are only 2 lowest cost solutions to this setup, and they're mirror images of each other, which makes sense since we didn't filter by direction in our circular permutations.  Am intentionally not stating what they are here.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Yes, I am new to Perl as well as programming at all. It is a great help to see how one can solve a certain problem, because I am not yet used to the language. But I hope that will change soon.