# Pseudocode for Branch and Bound method to solve TSP.

Tags: pseudocode, traveling-salesman, branch-and-bound

I'm looking for a pseudocode for B&B algorithm for Travelling Salesman problem. I found this:
[TSP - Branch and bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154171/tsp-branch-and-bound)
but links that somebody gave there as an answer didn't help me so far. Do you have any examples os that pseudocode?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are several different B&B algorithms for TSP. Do you mean the approach that doesn't use linear programming (LP) at all but is based on row/column reductions (Little et al. 1963)? Or methods involving taking the LP relaxation and then possibly adding cuts (there are many such methods)?

Comment: I meant Little algorithm, but I found it already, but thanks for respond :)

Comment: Would it be possible to include where did you find it?